# Using javax.servlet in jdk11 and wildfly27

Tags: java, wildfly

I try to use https://github.com/mitre/HTTP-Proxy-Servlet in wildfly27 with jdk11

I get the following error
Should it work as it is , or should i replace javax with jakarta?

Is this problem because i use wildfly, and it won't happen with another server app like tomcat?

```
11:23:55,153 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."proxy.war".undertow-deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."proxy.war".undertow-deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: Failed to start service
        at org.jboss.msc@1.4.13.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1731)
        at org.jboss.msc@1.4.13.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UT010009: Servlet proxyHostServer of type class org.mitre.dsmiley.httpproxy.ProxyServlet does not implement jakarta.servlet.Servlet
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.api.ServletInfo.<init>(ServletInfo.java:98)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@27.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.createServletConfig(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:660)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@27.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.start(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:288)
        at org.jboss.msc@1.4.13.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
        at org.jboss.msc@1.4.13.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
```

Comment: Wildfly 2.7 is JakartaEE compliant, but "Smiley's HTTP Proxy Servlet" requires a JavaEE container.

Comment: @StephenC What should i do to use "Smiley's HTTP Proxy Servlet" in wildfly27

Comment: Look for an alternative.  It is not compatible.   Or hack on the source  code.

Comment: @StephenC i have a few servlet that use javax.servlet and i need to upgrade to wilfly27
So i need to change code to jakarta, can't look for an alternative

Comment: In that case change the code to jakarta.  The source code is available.

Comment: There will soon be a feature pack that can be added to WildFly which will perform the package migration in a deployment from Jakarta EE 8 to Jakarta EE 9 https://issues.redhat.com/browse/WFLY-17219.